# Merge statement inside if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this script:

```
DECLARE @TenantId INT = 1
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
            FROM [DB1].[Client1].information_schema.tables 
           WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' 
             AND [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo'
             AND table_name='MyTable')
BEGIN

    MERGE info.[MyTable] AS t
    USING (
            SELECT [Id],
                   [Name]                  
              FROM [DB1].[Client1].dbo.MyTable
          ) s   
       ON (t.[Id] = s.[Id] AND t.[TenantId] = @TenantId)

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET      
            t.[Name] = s.[Name]

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT ([Id], [TenantId], [Name])
        VALUES (s.[Id], @TenantId, s.[Name]);

END
```

Why is giving me an error on the select inside the USING, if the table doesn't exists?, I cannot run the script when the table doesn't exists. If table exists is fine.

Comment: Because the table doesn't exist so it can't compile your query. You either need to ensure the table will exist or move the query to be inside dynamic sql.

Comment: When you run something, a query plan is made for each and every statement, including those that are inside if blocks. Everything must exist for it to complete successfully. You could do this by moving the merge into a stored procedure.

Comment: thanks you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented if the table does not exist then the compiler will error.  Try this:

```
 DECLARE @TenantId INT = 1
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM [DB1].[Client1].information_schema.tables 
               WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE' 
                 AND [TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'dbo'
                 AND table_name='MyTable')

    BEGIN
    Declare @Sql Varchar(8000)
    Set @Sql =
   'MERGE info.[MyTable] AS t
    USING (
            SELECT [Id],
                   [Name]                  
              FROM [DB1].[Client1].dbo.MyTable
          ) s   
       ON (t.[Id] = s.[Id] AND t.[TenantId] = ' + Convert(Varchar(8000), @TenantId) + ')

    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET      
            t.[Name] = s.[Name]

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT ([Id], [TenantId], [Name])
        VALUES (s.[Id], '+ Convert(Varchar(8000), @TenantId) + ', s.[Name]);
    Exec (@Sql)
END
```